# Free pascal count array values with the same value

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

I have a text file with city names and their districts ex:

```
15
Vilnius Vilniaus 541278
Dusetos Utenos 4211
Alytus Alytaus 69859
Druskininkai Alytaus 16890
Ignalina Utenos 6307
Kavarskas Utenos 753
Lazdijai Alytaus 5027
Simnas Alytaus 1940
Trakai Vilniaus 5504
Utena Utenos 33086
Veisiejai Alytaus 1673
Vievis Vilniaus 5246
Lentvaris Vilniaus 11832
Visaginas Utenos 28438
Zarasai Utenos 8001
```

And I need to filter all the cities to same districts...
How can it be achieved with free pascal ? I would use array but free pascal has only numeric indexes array[ num..num2 ] I think :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can keep an array of districts you've seen so far. The index of that  array can identify the district in a  multidimensional array of districts then the cities in that district.

Comment: Can you explain, *filter all the cities to same districts*? What is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have only numeric indices, but classes can override the `[]` notation.

You can probably use one of the [various container implementations](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Data_Structures,_Containers,_Collections) to do what you want. Maybe look at the `gmap` or `ghashmap` units.